# Asking a wildcarded actor selection

Tags: scala, akka

Is it possible to send a message to a wildcarded actor selection that we expect to match multiple actors, and do something with all of the responses?

My first thought was something like this:

```
sequence(context.actorSelection("/actors*") ? Message).onSuccess {
    println("The results are " + _)
}
```

But that doesn't work as the ask does not return an Iterable over all the futures created by sending the message to all of the actors, just a single future that returns when any actor replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difficulty here, as senia pointed out is that you will be asking an unknown number of actors for responses, making it really difficult to know when you are done waiting for responses.  If you are cool specifying a timeout for waiting that will always be hit before you get a response, then I suppose you could do something like this:

```
//Message to send to the temp actor that handles request/response to the selection
case class AskSelection(path:String, msg:Any, askTimeout:FiniteDuration)

//Actor that handles the request to aggregate responses from a selection
class SelectionAsker extends Actor{
  import context._      
  var responses:List[Any] = List.empty      

  def receive = waitingForRequest

  def waitingForRequest:Receive = {
    case request @ AskSelection(path, msg, askTO) =>                
      system.actorSelection(path) ! msg          
      setReceiveTimeout(askTO)
      become(waitingForResponses(sender, askTO.fromNow))
  }

  def waitingForResponses(originator:ActorRef, deadline:Deadline):Receive = {
    case ReceiveTimeout => 
      originator ! responses
      context.stop(self)          
    case any =>           
      responses = any :: responses
      setReceiveTimeout(deadline.timeLeft)
  }
}

//Factory to create the selection asker
object SelectionAsker{
  def apply(fact:ActorRefFactory) = fact.actorOf(Props[SelectionAsker])
}
```

The general idea here is that another short lived and temporary actor is used as the go between to handle aggregating the responses from the selection.  It has to wait the entire amount of the supplied ask timeout before responding to the sender because as I mentioned, it does not know how many responses to wait for.  You could use it like this:

```
val system = ActorSystem("test")
system.actorOf(Props[ActorA], "actor-a")
system.actorOf(Props[ActorB], "actor-b")
implicit val timeout = Timeout(2 seconds)
import system._

val asker = SelectionAsker(system)
(asker ? AskSelection("/user/actor*", "foo", 1 seconds)) onComplete { tr =>
  println(tr)
}

class ActorA extends Actor{
  def receive = {
    case _ => 
      sender ! "a"
  }
}

class ActorB extends Actor{
  def receive = {
    case _ => 
      sender ! "b"   
  }
}
```

It's not pretty, but it could work for you if this is what you really need to do.  But you should probably make sure that it is what you want to do first and that there are not better and easier options first as this is a bit of extra code to have to add for your use case.

Comment: One solution would be to use receiveTimeout together with a Deadline (to avoid the explicitness of the scheduler)

Comment: @ViktorKlang, good idea.  I updated the solution accordingly.

Comment: You'll want to use a Deadline and used the ``remaining`` time for each successive setReceiveTimeout until DeadLine.isOverdue where you are done. Makes sense?

Comment: @ViktorKlang, much better idea.  I missed the point for the first refactor.  After reading your response, I realized the flaw in that I was not rescheduling the `receiveTimeout` after the first response which could lead to issues.  I hope the current solution is more in line with what you were suggesting.

Comment: I have provided an implementation of this when working with Akka from java https://github.com/campnic/akka-java-utils/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/campnic/SelectionAsker.java in case anyone would prefer that.  As with everything in Java, its quite a bit more verbose then Scala :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get all responses to the mailbox of actor `self`, you could use `!` method with explicit `sender` argument like this:

```
context.actorSelection("/actors*").!(Message)(self)
```

In `Actor` `self` is `implicit` so compiler will use it as `sender` implicitly. You could just send message:

```
context.actorSelection("/actors*") ! Message
```

If you want to do something special with all responses you could create additional actor and specify it as `sender` in `!` method, but you'll have to stop this additional actor manually.

Comment: The pipeTo was for explanatory purposes - the real goal is to make use of the future returned from the ask. I'll edit to make that clearer.
If I were to use an additional actor, I wouldn't have any way to tell that it could be stopped would I?

Comment: @MHarris: You don't know how many responses you should get, so you don't know when to stop waiting for responses. You could process each response separately, or you could wait for some constant time. In case of temporary actor you could ask (`?`) it for all received responses after timeout using `scheduleOnce` method of `scheduler`, temporary actor should stop itself after sending all collected responses.