# Is it safe for Akka actor become method to close over immutable state?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

The purpose here is to implement a very simple cache for an actor that needs to call an external service (or some expensive but highly cacheable operation) without using mutable state.

```
class A extends Actor{
  def receive = {
    case GetCommand => 
      val response = callExternalService()
      context.become(receiveWithCache(response))
      context.system.scheduler.schedule(1 day, 1 day, self, InvalidateCache)
      sender ! response
  }
  def receiveWithCache(cachedResponse:R): PartialFunction[Any,Unit] = {
    case GetCommand => sender ! cachedResponse
    case InvalidateCache => context.unbecome
  }
}
```

I know there are more advanced ways to implement this, among which a fully fledged CacheSystem that can be found in the Akka patterns pages, but in some cases that really isn't required.

Plus, it's interesting to know the answer if using become like this is safe.

Comment: Looking forward to the answer myself since this is pretty elegant.

Comment: Why wouldn't closing over immutable state be safe?

Comment: 1) I don't think avoiding (local) state at all costs is reasonable —please enlighten me if I'm missing something—and 2) wouldn't it look nicer to use an anonymous (partial) function with `context.become` instead of a method?

Comment: @ErikAllik 1) But there is no cost involved. Actually it might be better if you avoided a mutable local state as is unsafe to share that with methods the use futures. 2) Maybe it does for such a simple case but if the receive method is more complex I don't think it would look better.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I know this technique is sound and should be good for you to use.  It's actually a more clever way to get around having to have a mutable `var response` in your code.  I actully used this technique in an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18698200/asking-a-wildcarded-actor-selection/18702966) and Viktor from the Akka team seemed to think it was a good solution.  One thing though, you can change:

```
def receiveWithCache(cachedResponse:R): PartialFunction[Any,Unit] = {
  case GetCommand => sender ! cachedResponse
  case InvalidateCache => context.unbecome
}
```

to:

```
def receiveWithCache(cachedResponse:R): Receive = {
  case GetCommand => sender ! cachedResponse
  case InvalidateCache => context.unbecome
}
```

The `Receive` type is a shorthand alias for `PartialFunction[Any,Unit]`.

Comment: It is even the recommended way of doing this. To expand on the question: `become` does not leave the actor context, so it is completely safe, even for mutable state.